# Existence and uniqueness of a solution of a linear, inhomogeneous, implicit ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

**Problem**: Given the differential equation $$x^2 y''(x)+4x\,y'(x)+2\,y(x)=r(x)$$ for some function $r\in C^2(\mathbb R)$, and the inital values $$y(0)=y_0,\qquad y'(0)=y_1,$$ how can one analyse whether a solution $y\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ exists locally around $x_0=0$ and/or is locally unique, depending on the choice of $y_0$ and $y_1$?

**Some thoughts**

- Obviously, the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf is not applicable around $x_0=0$ as the ODE is implicit. For $x_0\neq 0$, however, one has an interval which does not contain $0$, which yields an explicit ODE of the form $y''+\frac 4x y+\frac{2}{x^2} y=\frac{r}{x^2}$, where one observes that the associated homogeneous equation has the general solution $y(x)=\frac{c_1}{x}+\frac{c_2}{x^2}$ for $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb R$ on either $(0,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$.
- If $c_1\neq 0\neq c_2$, then the solution is unbounded. However, this does not imply that the general solution of the inhomogeneous problem is unbounded at $x_0=0$ (which would have yielded a contradiction to the existence of a solution).
- $y(0)=y_0$ implies that $y_0=\frac{r(0)}{2}$.
- The fist term of the ODE $x^2\,y''$ is differentiable with $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^2 y''(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2 y''(h)-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} h\,y''(h)=0$ (using the continuity of $y''$ and thus the boundedness on some interval around $0$). Although we do not know whether $y'''$ exists or not, we still have an expression for the derivative of $x^2 y''$ at $x_0=0$. This means that, after differentiating the ODE at $x_0=0$, we get $6\,y'(0)=r'(x)$ or $y_1=\frac{r'(0)}{6}$.
- The last two points imply that the ODE does have no solution for $y_0\neq r(0)/2$ or $y_1\neq r'(0)/6$. This reduces the problem to the analysis of the case $y_0=r(0)/2$, $y_1=r'(0)/6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the existence and uniqueness of the solution**

Starting with the thoughts mentioned in the original question, we know that $$y_0=\frac 12 r(0)\qquad\text{and}\qquad y_1=\frac 16 r'(0)$$ must be satisfied. (Otherwise, no solution exists.) Hence, we only need to show that a solution exists in this case, and that it is unique. On $(0,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$, as shown in the *Thoughts* section in the original post, a basis of the vector space of solutions is $\{x\mapsto x^{-1},x\mapsto x^{-2}\}$. A general solution is hence of the form $y_p(x)=c_1/x+c_2/x^2$. Variation of constants yields the equation $0=c_1'(x)/x+c_2'(x)/x^2$ with $c_1,c_2\in C^1(\mathbb R)$. Plugging $y_p$ into the original ODE implies $r(x)=-c_1'(x)-2c_2'(x)/x$. Multiplying this by $1/x$ and adding it to the condition for variation of constants results in $c_1'(x)=r(x)$.

This means that $$y_p(x)=\frac 1x \int_0^x r(t)\,\mathrm dt+\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x t\,r(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$

In order for a solution to exist on some neighborhood around $x_0=0$, we have some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathbb R$ such that $y(x)=y_p(x)+\alpha_1/x+\alpha_2/x^2$ solves the ODE. Since $$\lim_{x\to 0}y_p(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(f(x)-\frac{x\,f(x)}{2x}\right)=\frac12 f(0)$$ using l'Hospital (especially, the limit exists, which was not clear in the first place), we know that $\lim_{x\to 0} (\alpha_1/x+\alpha_2/x^2)=0$, which is only possible for $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$. This directly implies that $y(x)=y_p(x)$ must hold, which gives existence and local uniqueness of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

first solve the homogeneous equation
$$x^2y''+4xy'+2y=0~~~(1)$$ by taking Euler's prescription $y=x^m$
$$\implies m(m-1)x^{m-2}+4mx^{m-1}+2x^m=0 \implies m=1,2$$ 
So $y_1=x, y_2=x^2$ are two solutions of (1).
Next by variation parameters we have the solution of
$$x^2Y''+4xY'+2Y=r(x)~~~~(2)$$
as $$Y(x)=C_1  x + C_2 x^2,$$
Where $$C_1=\int \frac{-x^2 r(x)}{W(x)} dx+D_1, C_2=\int \frac{x r(x)}{W(x)} dx+D_2$$,
Here $W(x)$ is the Wronskian $[y_1y'_2-y'_1 y_2]=-x^2.$

Comment: I don't think that the solutions to the homogeneous are $x$ and $x^2$, but $x^{-1}$ and $x^{-2}$.
And how does uniqueness and/or existence follow from this result?

Comment: @st. math Oh! yes you are right I have edited my answer. Existence will depend on $r(x)$ and its domain.